# Is it safe to use qry.map_async() when the number of query results is large?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an AppEngine cron job that queries the datastore and then needs to do some work on each entity returned by the query. The number of entities returned by the query is expected to sometimes be large (>1000).

My goal is to maximize concurrency and also keep memory usage low - since the expected number of results is large, they may not fit in memory.

Given the large # of results, should I iterate over them like this:

```
qry = Model.query()
qit = qry.iter()
while (yield qit.has_next_async()):
    entity = qit.next()
    # Do something with entity
```

...or is it safe to use the faster map_async() to operate on an arbitrarily large result set?

```
@ndb.tasklet
def callback(entity):
    # Do something with entity

qry = Model.query()
yield qry.map_async(callback)
```

I've read all of the docs and even looked at the guts of the implementation and it's not entirely clear what the limitations of these operations are for large result sets.

Comment: Using "yield something_async()" isn't any improvement over using the synchronous API unless your code is running in a tasklet (in which case, it still won't run any faster, but other stuff can run at the same time).

Comment: Also, ">1000" covers a lot. Is it >10,000? >100,000? >1,000,000? At some point the best approach changes.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes my code is running in a tasklet, and I realize it's not really "faster" but rather allows other tasklets to run at the same time. Thanks for clarifying. 

As for the number of entities, I expect the number to go as high as perhaps 10,000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map reads a batch at a time and then calls the callback for each entity in the batch. So that should be fine. You can experiment with batch size as well.

A difference is if the callback itself does more IO. Then the for loop version presumably waits for each item to be fully processed, while the map just starts all callbacks and only waits for them at the very end. So, more parallelism, bot also potentially more memory use.

Comment: I've implemented this cron job using the map_async implementation inside a tasklet. The query that I'm mapping over typically has 1000 or more results. After about 300 callbacks finish successfully, I get a query expiration error:"The requested query has expired. Please restart it with the last cursor to read more results." Any suggestions on what I should do? Switch to cursors perhaps? I should mention that each callback in turn does a map_async over different entities (typically between 1 and 3 entities) for each of the outer query results.

Comment: I expect that breaking the query up in "pages" of e.g. 100 entities linked by cursors will solve this. The error message comes from the discrepancy between the lifetime of an active query (I think 30 seconds) and the time your cron job (really a task queue request) has (10 minutes). And since, as you say, you're doing lots of work for each callback, you take a long time processing the entire query. The concurrency introduced by map() is limited to the batch size anyway, and if you have too many outstanding RPCs you will be throttled anyway.